# Calibration of MQ sensors and programming logarithmic function in MCU

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, circuit-design, sensor, pic

I'm developing a microcontroller-based project for a gas sensor. I want to use MQ2 or MQ6, so I looked at the following sites:

1. https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/gas-detection-and-ppm-measurement-using-pic-microcontroller-and-mq-gas-sensor
2. https://sandboxelectronics.com/?p=165

They explain the procedure of design and **calibration of the sensor**

I highlighted the **calibration** because it is interesting.

- I want to understand the graph, given in the datasheet, of Rs/R0 vs PPM of the gas which is a logarithmic graph, but when I come the the interpretations of the programmers in the two sites, I did not grasp the method used by the two. In the first site the author presented the first point of the graph as (log200, log2) and in the second site the author presented the first point of the graph as (log200, 0.21). From where does the 0.21 come?
- I did not understand the following code that plots the logarithmic function in the MCU program:
  `(pow(10, (((log(rs_ro_ratio) - pcurve[1]) / pcurve[2]) + pcurve[0])));`

Why do the programmers use
`(((log(rs_ro_ratio) - pcurve[1]) / pcurve[2]) + pcurve[0]))`? what are the parameters in terms of the graph characteristics?

Can anyone explain how this function is derived from the graph?

I'm not sure of the answer, but I find this post important so I share it:

http://davidegironi.blogspot.com/2017/05/mq-gas-sensor-correlation-function.html#.Yx4o63ZKjIU

Comment: You need to look at the libraries being used.

Comment: @DKNguyen, the problem is not in the libraries, If we try to get the equation of the graph given in the datasheet we find it as a linear equation of the form y=ax+b (of course in logarithmic scale), y=Rs/R0, a=Pcurve[2], and b should be pcurve[0], but when I try to compare it with the equation used in the program, I mess somthing and I could not get the same equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see sloppy math and poor programming practices in the links. Some #defines and/or enums would help. Here is how to do it in Excel. They are not using *y = ax + b*, but I prefer it also. Sometimes it is easier to derive it yourself than try to understand someone else's mess.

For a sanity check, I plugged data into the equations at the bottom.

[image]

With "show formulas" enabled:
[image]